# In Java memory management, what does 'PS' stand for?

Tags: java

Whenever I see reference to memory in Java, the various spaces are always prefixed with 'PS'.  What does 'PS' mean?  It's starting to bother me... my only guess so far is 'pool space', but that would be redundant.

Examples:

- PS Eden Space
- PS Survivor Space
- PS Tenured Space (Old Generation)
- PS Perm Gen (Permanent Generation)

Comment: Can you give a more specific reference to some document you're reading?

Comment: One place I've seen it is in the jconsole application that comes packaged with the JDK.  After connecting to a JVM instance, the Memory tab has a drop-down where you can select a memory pool to view - most of them are prefixed with 'PS'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I could be wrong but i'm pretty sure it stands for Parallel Scavenge (has to do with garbage collection)

[Improving Java Application Performance and Scalability by Reducing Garbage Collection Times and Sizing Memory Using JDK 1.4.1: Parallel Scavenge Collector](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-156457.html#2.2.1)

Comment: Awesome, that looks like it.  The OCD part of me has been satisfied, thanks very much! :)