# Different behaviour on 2 containers of same tomcat image run on 2 Debian servers

Tags: docker, tomcat

When I run docker tomcat manager on 2 Debian servers I have these 2 displays:

Tomcat1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kucJQ.png

Tomcat2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygOCh.png

Tomcat status memory pools are listed with different names as "**PS** < memory pool>" in Tomcat 1 and only "< memory pool >" in Tomcat 2 (like "PS Eden Space" vs "Eden Space").

Both container are run the same way :

```html
docker run   --name tomcat-test   -it   -p 8083:8080   -v /tmp/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml   -v /tmp/context.xml:/tmp/context.xml   tomcat:8.5-jdk8-openjdk  /bin/bash -c "mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps /usr/local/tomcat/webapps2; mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist /usr/local/tomcat/webapps; cp /tmp/context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml; catalina.sh run"
```

with same param xml files:

```html
cat /tmp/context.xml
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
  -->
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

and

```html
# cat /tmp/tomcat-users.xml
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Both server are the same versions:

```html
# cat /etc/debian_version
9.13

# docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.15
```

Any idea why there is such difference? Shouldn't 2 containers running the same image do the sctrictly same behaviour?
It's a small difference but I'm wondering if there is such difference I have seen, maybe there are other I don't see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the memory pools depend on the garbage collector implementation used. This in turn depends on the characteristics (memory, number of real/virtual CPUs) of the servers on which the JVM runs.

The instance reporting memory pools prefixed by `PS` must be using the parallel garbage collector (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6932810/11748454)). The other instance is probably using the serial garbage collector.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33210606/11748454) on how the GC implementation used depends upon the characteristics of the server.

Comment: Indeed both server are same OS but different harware: 20G/2 vCPUs vs 15G/1 vCPU. I'll check that. thank you for help